# MovieContext.Movies' is inaccessible due to its protection level error in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#

Need help to figure out the issue.

**`MovieContext.cs` file:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace AspNetCoreWebApi6.Models
{
    public class MovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovieContext(DbContextOptions<MovieContext> options)
            :base(options)
        {
        }
        DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MoviesController.cs file**

```
using AspNetCoreWebApi6.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AspNetCoreWebApi6.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MovieContext _dbContext;

        public MoviesController(MovieContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        //Get api/Movies
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Movie>>> GetMovies() {

            if (_dbContext.Movies == null) { 
                return NotFound();
            }
            return await _dbContext.Movies.ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

**Models/Movie.cs file**

```
namespace AspNetCoreWebApi6.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Change Protection Level

```
public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
```